# Sending data using anchor link in php codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project in which i want to send the 'id' of data from view to controller. But it is not working. I am new to codeIgniter kindly help me. Where i am doing mistake please help.

Here is the code of my View:

```
 <?php foreach ($records as $item):?>


                <tr>
                <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>"><?php echo $item['ration_type'];?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['reg_date']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['exp_date'] ?></td>

                     </tr>


        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Here are the pictures:

[image]
This is the layout. When ever i click on the link. It displays this message.

[image]

But we can see the value and url in page source.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: But you have not created a router in codeigniter to match that!

Comment: What controller are you trying to pass this data to?

Comment: Also sugest you use CI format `href="<?php echo base_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail/<?php echo $item['id']?>"`

Comment: This is also not working.

Comment: if you change `<td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>"><?php echo $item['ration_type'];?></a></td>` to `<td><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>"><?php echo $item['ration_type'];?></a></td>`

Comment: @elddenmedio You are right Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>"><?php echo $item['ration_type'];?></a></td> to <td><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>rationgroup/viewdetail?id=<?php echo $item['id']?>"><?php echo $item['ration_type'];?></a></td>
```

This is the correct by answere by @elddenmedio